# Jersey client file upload code 415 - unsupported Media Type

Tags: java, rest, file-upload, jersey

im trying to create a jersey client to upload files. I have a web serice and a client. But i get everytime a 415 - unsupported Media Type and i don't know what the problem could be.
I`ve searched the i-net / stackoverflow but i cant find a proper solution for my problem. I tried many solutions but without success. You can see this as comments in my code.

Client:

```
private static void clientFileUpload() throws IOException {
    ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();
    Client client       = ClientBuilder.newClient(config);
    client.register(MultiPartFeature.class);

    URI baseUri            = UriBuilder.fromUri("http://localhost:8080/vogella.jersey.first").build();
    final WebTarget target = client.target(baseUri);

    final FileDataBodyPart filepart           = new FileDataBodyPart("files", new File("C:/Users/admin/Downloads/testtext.txt"));
    final FormDataMultiPart formDataMultiPart = new FormDataMultiPart();
    final FormDataMultiPart multiPart         = (FormDataMultiPart) formDataMultiPart.field("foo", "bar").bodyPart(filepart);
    multiPart.setMediaType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE);
    Response response = target.path("rest").path("hello").path("upload")
                              .request()
                              .header("Content-Type", MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)  
                              .post(Entity.entity(multiPart, multiPart.getMediaType()));
    //.header("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data"
    //.header("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;charset=UTF-8")
    //multiPart.getMediaType()
    //"Content-Tpye: multipart/form-data"
    System.out.println("--> " + response.getMediaType());
    System.out.println("--> " + response.getStringHeaders());

    System.out.println(":: RESPONSE : " + response);
    System.out.println(":: STATUSCODE: " + response.getStatus() + " -- Reason: " + response.getStatusInfo());
    String output = response.readEntity(String.class);      
    System.out.println(":: OUTPUT: " + output);

}
```

WebService:
I tried 2 different solutions but i can't find my mistake.

```
package vogella.jersey.first;

import java.io.File;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataMultiPart;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPart;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;

@Path("/hello")
public class Hello {


@GET
@Path("/test")
@Produces("application/xml")
public MyBean getBean() {
    return new MyBean("Hello MyBean", 42);
}

@POST
@Path("/test")
@Consumes("application/xml")
public String postMyBean(MyBean myBean) {
    return myBean.anyString;
}

@POST
@Path("/upload")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
//@Produces("multipart/mixed")
public MultiPart post (final FormDataMultiPart multiPart) {
    System.out.println("::: THIS IS THE MULTIPART MESSAGE: " + multiPart);
    return multiPart;
}

@POST
@Path("/ul")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces("text/plain")
public Response uploadFile(final FormDataMultiPart form) {
    String output = "Done";
    return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
}
}
```

[Jersey REST files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbXmo.jpg)

Im able to send normal GET and Post Request to the server. But i need to send files too. I hope, someone can help me.

This is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

<display-name>vogella.jersey.first</display-name>

<servlet>

<servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-
class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
     <!-- Register resources and providers under com.vogella.jersey.first package. -->
<init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>vogella.jersey.first</param-value>
</init-param>
<!-- 
<init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
    <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature</param-value>
</init-param>
-->
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Is there anything in the server log or client response that might be useful for debugging the problem?

Comment: The Client response looks like this: `InboundJaxrsResponse{context=ClientResponse{method=POST, uri=http://localhost:8080/vogella.jersey.first/rest/hello/upload, status=415, reason=Unsupported Media Type}}` and if i display response.getMediaType(), the interesting part is, that my request has no fitting MediaType, but i dont understand the problem. `text/html;charset=utf-8` response.getStringHeaders(): `{Server=[Apache-Coyote/1.1], Content-Length=[1092], Date=[Tue, 15 Mar 2016 10:20:19 GMT], Content-Language=[en], Content-Type=[text/html;charset=utf-8]}`

Comment: What about server logs? Any errors? Did you register the MultiPartFeature with the server also?

Comment: I added the web.xml + the complete "webservice" code. Maybe that could help a little bit. As you can see it is similar to the vogella tutorial.

Comment: Can you modify the 4 lines After WebTarget declaration to `final FileDataBodyPart filepart = new FileDataBodyPart("files", new File("C:/Users/admin/Downloads/testtext.txt"), MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE);
    final FormDataMultiPart formDataMultiPart = new FormDataMultiPart();
    formDataMultiPart.setMediaType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE);
    formDataMultiPart.field("foo", "bar").bodyPart(filepart);`

Comment: I modified these 4 lines but the error is still existing -_-`

Comment: Can you paste the updated code? Also, Can you return a String as output from the method `post()` and provide `@Produces("text/plain")`. So we can identify if the issue is with recognizing the service.